# Mojave Home App

Tags: mojave, homekit

Mojave has the Home app, but is it possible to make it the HomeKit Hub?

Comment: According to the Ars Technica Mojave review https://arstechnica.com/features/2018/09/macos-10-14-mojave-the-ars-technica-review/#h20: `You can't use a desktop or laptop Mac as a HomeKit "home hub" for controlling your devices from off-network. You'll still need an Apple TV, HomePod, or properly configured iPad to do that.`